# HTTP POST with Basic Auth and Fields (libcurl c++)

Tags: c++, post, libcurl

I am trying to make an HTTP POST using libcurl. The HTTP POST needs to perform a Basic Authentication, include a field and send a file in multi part. What I am using at the moment is the following:

```
FILE* fo = nullptr;
std::string fullErrPath(errPath);
fullErrPath.append("debug.txt");
fo = fopen(fullErrPath.c_str(), "wb");

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

struct curl_httppost* formpost = nullptr;
struct curl_httppost* lastptr = nullptr;

struct curl_slist* headerlist = nullptr;
static const char buf[] = "Expect:";

const char* imgPath = "/path/to/image.jpg";

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "jpgdata",
             CURLFORM_FILE, imgPath,
             CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "image/jpeg",
             CURLFORM_END);


curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit",
             CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send"
             CURLFORM_END);

curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl) {

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urlupload);

    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);

    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "field=1");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, credentials);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, fo);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    // Response information
    int httpCode(0);
    static std::string httpData;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &httpData);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_formfree(formpost);
    curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);
    fclose(fo);
}
```

I left on purpose this part "//curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "field=1");" commented because I found online that it does not make sense to use it with CURLOPT_HTTPPOST. This is the [post](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2011-12/0272.html). But code above does not work. 
First, the http response code I get from the server is 400 and by checking "debug.txt", in fact, there is no data. I see only the header.
Second, I need to include the POST field "field=1", but I do not know how to do it without using the command "curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "field=1");".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to set [CURLOPT_USERPWD](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERPWD.html) for the Basic auth.

Then, you need to decide which format of the data you want to POST. Do you want it to be multipart formpost or "regular" - you cannot mix them as that's just how HTTP works. The curl_formadd() you're doing so far is multipart formpost, and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is the regular one ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").

So you say you want to add a "field=1" to the post, and to do that and keep this a multipart formpost you can insert the following snippet after your second call to `curl_formadd`. It adds another "part" to the post with the name and contents you asked for:

```
curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "field",
             CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "1"
             CURLFORM_END);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but I still receive error 400 from the server saying "missing data". I am doing it under Android. The manifest already has these parameters set <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>. Then I checked the file path and is correct. The file is there.